# Return value is different for calling and called methods in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm experiencing a strange issue.

Here are my functions in the same order as in original script.

```
function Get-JsonFileContent {    
    param(        
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$objects
    )

    $includeBlocks = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();    

    if ($null -ne $objects -and $objects.ToString() -ne '' -and $objects.psobject.properties.count -gt 0) {
        foreach ($obj in $objects) {            
            if ($null -ne $obj -and $null -ne $obj.Name -and $obj.Name.Trim() -ne '' -and $obj.Name.Length -gt 0) {
                
                $include = @"
                {
                    "name": "$($obj.Name)",                    
                    "age": "$($obj.Age)"                                       
                }
"@
                $includeBlocks.Add($include);
            }            
        }
    } 
    $content = @"
    {
        "items": {
            "includes": [
                $($includeBlocks -join ",")
            ]
        }
    }
"@
    Set-Content -Force -Path "D:\one.json" -Value $content;
    return $content;
}

function GenerateJsonModule {    
    .....
    ....
    $jsonFileContent = Get-JsonFileContent -objects $objects;
    Set-Content -Force -Path "D:\two.json" -Value $jsonFileContent;
}
```

The output of `one.json` is as expected:

```
{
        "items": {
            "includes": [
                                {
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "age": "30"                     
                },                {
                    "name": "Jane Doe",
                    "age": "40"                                      
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

But `two.json` adds numbers as many as the count of "include" blocks, like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
{
            "items": {
                "includes": [
                                    {
                        "name": "John Doe",
                        "age": "30"                     
                    },                {
                        "name": "Jane Doe",
                        "age": "40"                                      
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Why is the same string output different for the called and the calling methods. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: In short: any output - be it from a PowerShell command, an operator-based expression, or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent to a file or via the pipeline to another command) is _implicitly output_ from a script or function. To simply _discard_ such output, use `$null = ...`.
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those numbers are being generated inside of your first function `Get-JsonFileContent` every time [the `Add` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.add?view=net-7.0) of your array list is invoked.

The line is `$includeBlocks.Add($include)`.
The `Add` method returns the index of the item you just added.

The solution is to discard that return value. This can be done with the following: `$includeBlocks.Add($include) | out-null`.

The reason that this is happening specifically when you invoke the first method from your second method is that PowerShell function returns are not strictly enforced. Anything placed into the pipeline by your function will be captured by whatever consumes the pipeline, not just the object which you explicitly place after the keyword `return`. Also note that those values are placed in the pipeline and consumed immediately rather than just when the function call completes.

The reason you don't get those numbers when creating `one.json` is because, within function 1, you aren't exporting the return value of a function. You are simply building your object and exporting it.

Function 2 is using the return from function 1, which contains all the data on the pipeline. In this case that is the numbers returned from the `add` method and the object you intended to return.

If you check the type of the object returned by function 1, you will see that it is an array.

Comment: @mklement0, thanks for the clarification. Answer edited.